# Linkage disequilibrium plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tile, geom

everyone,
I would like some help to identify if the chart model for representing linkage disequilibrium can be created with ggplot2.

Something like in this link:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322918111/figure/fig1/AS:960114349580299@1605920507474/Linkage-disequilibrium-LD-map-across-the-7-SNPs-The-measure-of-LD-D-is-shown_Q320.jpg

Comment: Maybe [LDLinkR](https://github.com/CBIIT/LDlinkR) could be useful? It seems to work with a web API, not ggplot2 though.

Comment: Pretty sure could this be achieved using `ggplot2`. I would approach this using `patchwork`, i.e. create two separate plots. Tricky part which requires some effort and math is to rotate the rectangles for the heatmap.

Comment: ... see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71831586/12993861) on an approach to achieve rotated tiles